# Error message Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
    ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST_01]       
     (
        @StartDate  DateTime,
        @EndDate    DateTime
     )
    AS      
    BEGIN      
      SET NOCOUNT ON;  
      Declare @sql as nvarchar(MAX);
      SET @sql = @sql + ';WITH CTE_ItemDetails
                MAX(D.Name) as Name,
                SUM(ISNULL(DT.col1, 0)) AS col1,
                SUM(ISNULL(DT.col2, 0)) AS col2,
                SUM(ISNULL(DT.col3, 0)) AS col3,
                GROUPING(D.ItemType) AS ItemTypeGrouping
            FROM Items D
                INNER JOIN Details DT ON DT.ItemId = D.ItemId
                INNER JOIN Report R ON R.ReportId = DT.ReportId
                where 1=1'
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= ' + @StartDate + 'AND  R.ReportDate <=' + @EndDate +')' 

            IF @someOtherVariable is not  null
            SET @sql = @sql + ' AND R.someColumn IN (''' +replace(@someOtherVariableValues,',','')+''+')' 

            SET @sql = @sql + 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM CTE_ItemDetails'
            EXECUTE (@sql)  
    END
```

I have a stored procedure that is similar to the T-SQL code above. 
(Note that i have removed lots of code that i feel isn't relevant to the error i'm getting)
I'm getting the below error when i execute it.

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

My parameters have values in below format

```
exec TEST_01 @StartDate=N'4/1/2016 12:00:00 AM',@EndDate=N'4/30/2016 12:00:00 AM'
```

It looks like the trouble is in the way i'm dynamically setting the SQL statement at line below

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= ' + @StartDate + 'AND  R.ReportDate <=' + @EndDate +')'
```

What is the best date formatting i can apply to avoid the error.

Comment: You need to quote dates, you should change it to `@sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= ''' + @StartDate + ''' AND R.ReportDate <= ''' + @EndDate + ''')'`

Comment: @Siyual this returns the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use parameters via `sp_executesql`.

But your immediate problem is this line:

```
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= ' + @StartDate + 'AND  R.ReportDate <=' + @EndDate +')'
```

It should look more like:

```
SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 121) + ''' AND R.ReportDate <= ''' + convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 121) +''')' ;
```

Note the inclusion of explicit type casting to a string and the double single quotes so the date literal is not interpreted as `2016 - 04 - 14` (i.e. 2000).

The better method of using parameters looks like:

```
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (R.ReportDate >= @StartDate AND R.ReportDate <= @EndDate)' ;

. . .
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@StartDate date, @EndDate date)', @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

It is easier to read the SQL statement.  The type issues are handled through parameters.  And, the query plan is more readily stashed.  Unfortunately, parameters only work for constants, not for column or table names, for instance.

Comment: what will happen if i use `sp_executesql` and pass a parameter that has not been added to @sql string because it was found to be null or empty?. I'm asking this because i'm adding a few more parameters (not shown in the script i posted initially). I have updated my the code to show this.

Comment: @StackTrace . . . If the parameters are declared in the second and third arguments, then it doesn't matter if it is in the SQL string.